# File download from url using HttpURLConnection |HTTP 400 if file name contain space

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, fileinputstream

I'm trying to download the files from url(soap request) using http connection, and below is my code, while executing i'm getting http = 400, because of file Name contain space `(ac abc.pdf)`

```
        String downloadFileName = "ac abc.pdf";
        String saveDir = "D:/download";

        String baseUrl = "abc.com/AttachmentDownload?Filename=";
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl + downloadFileName);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", url.toString());

        String userCredentials = "user:pass";
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", userCredentials);

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
                String saveFilePath = saveDir + downloadFileName;

                try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath)) {
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
```

while executing the above code getting the below output

```
responsecode400
response messageBad Request
No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: 400
```

let me know how can we format the url with the above situation

Comment: I think more info about actual error can be found by consuming `connection.getErrorStream()`

Comment: `The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.` Is the SOAP server yours?

Comment: Check this [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/)

Comment: question updated - if file name contain space received HTTP 400, please suggest how can we handle this situation

Comment: Have you tried [base64 encoding your `Authorization` header](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html)?

Comment: @vstm  not required encoding authorization, we check with team they are directly pass the credentials without encode/decode

Comment: What about URL encoding your URL ? A space is actually written `%20` when used inside a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces and some other symbols are not well tollerated in URL. You need to escape or encode them change your code

```
URL url = new URL(baseUrl + downloadFileName);
```

To:

```
URL url = new URL(baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(downloadFileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

That should resolve your problem. Besides there are Open Source libraries that resolve your issue for you. See [Apache commons](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) which is a popular solution. Another solution is [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) library (version 1.5.0.2). It contains class `HttpClient` that allows you to do things very simple:

```
httpClient.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(downloadFileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()", HttpClient.HttpMethod.POST);
```

This will return ByteBuffer that contains the response as raw bytes. The same class has method `sendHttpRequest` to get Textual response. Both methods throw `IOException` in case of failure. Here is the link to an article that explains where to get [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) library as well as what utilities it has. In the article the `HttpClient` class  is not mentioned (It is a new feature), but the library comes with well written javadoc. So look for javadoc for HttpClient class in that library.